# How to get current nonce that I need to send along with a transaction?

Tags: nonce

I wish you send nonce with every transaction so that I can store my nonce in DB and can override a specific transaction if it is pending for a while.

I know I can use `eth.getTransactionCount("accountAddress");` to get the number of transactions sent from a specific address and this will be the nonce.

But, the transactionCount only returns the count of mined transactions and not exactly sent transactions.

For e.g., if I send a transaction with nonce 18, and it's not mined yet. And I try to send next transaction from the same account and I calculate transaction count for this address, the transaction count returns 18 (but I should send transaction with nonce 19, right?). So the question is simple:

**How can I calculate the nonce for my next transaction keeping the case in mind where there may be pending transactions from the same address?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `eth.getTransactionCount("accountAddress", "pending");`